# Extrapolating a fitted curve with predict nls in R

Tags: r, predict, nls, extrapolation

I'm trying to predict a nls fit in R. 
My values are intensities (y) and excitation energy (x). My code is the following:

```
mydata<-read.delim("TrapDepthExcSpec.txt", 
               header = TRUE)

x <- mydata[1:5,1] 
y <- mydata[1:5,2] 

plot(x,y)

k <- 65
Et <- 2.16
m0 <-0.7
test <- k*((x-Et)^(3/2))/(x*((x-(Et*(1-(m0/0.79))))^2))
lines(x,test)

EtFit <- function(x, k, Et, m0) k*((x-Et)^(3/2))/(x*((x-(Et*(1- (m0/0.79))))^2))

FitEt <- nls(y~EtFit(x, k, Et, m0), 
        start = list(k = 65, Et = 2.16, m0 = 0.7), 
        control = list(maxiter = 500),
        algorithm = "port")

res <- coef(FitEt)
RES <- res[1]*((x-res[2])^(3/2))/(x*((x-(res[2]*(1-(res[3]/0.79))))^2))
lines(x,RES,col="red")

xall=mydata[,1]; yall=mydata[,2]
plot(xall,yall, col = "gray48", pch = 20)
lines(x,RES,col="red")

### predict nls ###

NewData <- as.matrix(cbind(x, RES))
colnames <- (NewData)
colnames(NewData) <- c("x", "y")

predict(FitEt, NewData, se.fit = TRUE, scale = NULL, df = Inf, interval =    c("none", "confidence", "prediction"), level = 0.95)
```

My problem is that it always just results in the fitted values and does not predict new ones.

I know that there is already a question like this in here, but it never got answered so that it works.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Your `NewData` does not seem to contain all columns needed by the model to predict any values. Namely, you need columns `x, k, Et, m0`.

Comment: It still just repeats the 5 fitted points for all new x vales

Comment: I solved it. Thank you

Comment: How did you solve it! Argh!